# Sequelize.Js-PostgreSQL How to get rows in associated tables from belonging table?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, has-many

I am trying to achieve retrieving associated rows in ReceiptItems, Payments from Receipts which are connected to each other hasMany and belongsTo methods.

Here my table relations :

```js
// One to Many Relationship between receiptitems and receipts
db.Receipts.hasMany(db.ReceiptItems,{ foreignKey : 'receipt_id'});
db.ReceiptItems.belongsTo(db.Receipts,{ foreignKey : 'receipt_id'});

// One to Many Relationship between ReceiptItems and Payments
// This relation exists due to solve the problem of paying the debts later on !
db.Receipts.hasMany(db.Payments, { foreignKey : 'receipt_id' });
db.Payments.belongsTo(db.Receipts, { foreignKey : 'receipt_id' });

// One to many Relationship between Receipts and Plates
db.Plates.hasMany(db.Receipts, { foreignKey : 'plate_id' });
db.Receipts.belongsTo(db.Plates, { foreignKey : 'plate_id' });
```

Here my method to find Receipts that belongs to the plate_id, it finds the receipts but it does not retrieve the ReceiptItems and Payments associated to that Receipts( Not null variables, I cannot see any field related to the associated tables in result of the successful comeback. )

```js
db.Receipts.findAll({
        where : {
          plate_id : result.plate_id
        }
      },{
        include : [ { associaton : db.ReceiptItems}, { association : db.Payments} ]
      }).then((receiptResult)=>{
        console.log(receiptResult);
      }).catch((receiptErr)=>{
        console.log(receiptErr);
      })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just have found out the reason why I encountered the problem.

First, just after where statement I had an extra closing block parenthesis and I have to use associations in the way below :

```js
db.Receipts.find({
        where : {
          plate_id : result.plate_id
        },
        include : [{ association : db.Receipts.associations.ReceiptItems},{ association : db.Receipts.associations.Payments }]
      }).then((receiptResult)=>{
        console.log(receiptResult);
      }).catch((receiptErr)=>{
        console.log(receiptErr);
      })
```